# Transferring files over SSH

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm SSHing into a remote server on the command line, and trying to copy a directory onto my local machine with the `scp` command. However, the remote server returns this "usage" message:

```
[Stewart:console/ebooks/discostat] jmm% scp -p ./styles/
usage: scp [-1246BCEpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
[Stewart:console/ebooks/discostat] jmm%
```

I'd like to be able to transfer files in both directions. From what I read, I thought the above command would work for downloading, and `scp -p [localpath] [remotepath]` for uploading?

Answer (score 803):

You need to `scp` something somewhere. You have `scp ./styles/`, so you're saying secure copy `./styles/`, but not where to copy it to.

Generally, if you want to download, it will go:

```bash
# download: remote -> local
scp user@remote_host:remote_file local_file
```

where `local_file` might actually be a directory to put the file you're copying in. To upload, it's the opposite:

```bash
# upload: local -> remote
scp local_file user@remote_host:remote_file
```

If you want to copy a whole directory, you will need `-r`. Think of `scp` as like `cp`, except you can specify a file with `user@remote_host:file` as well as just local files.

Edit: As noted in a comment, if the usernames on the local and remote hosts are the same, then the user can be omitted when specifying a remote file.

Comment: Note that if the user is the same on the remote host and the local host, the username can be omitted: scp hello.c myserver.net:~/projects/

Comment: Yes, true, I'll add a note about that. I included the user because then the examples I gave will always work. :)

Comment: Im having a hardtime on this.. is this correct. scp C:\filename.txt server1@server2:home

Comment: Please add bold formatting on "donload" and "upload".

Comment: "naturally" (I say naturally because I just wasted 15 minutes on this) you should not be connected to the remote host while attempting to "download" to local, because if you are executing the code from a remote instance, "local" will be interpreted as the "remote", if you see what I mean. So **don't** run ssh first.

Comment: -P for port / -r for folder coping

Comment: make sure to pass port as 
`scp -P port local_file user@remote_host:remote_file`
and
`scp -P port user@remote_host:remote_file local_file`

Comment: +1 I keep coming back to this. I love that the answer is extremely clear on defining the direction of transfer and order of parameters

Comment: If you want to use credentials don't forget to set the -i flag: 
scp -i rsa_file_path user@remote_host:remote_file local_file
This is recommended over passwords.

Answer (score 178):

If copying to/from your desktop machine, use WinSCP, or if on Linux, Nautilus supports SCP via the Connect To Server option.

scp can only copy files to a machine running sshd, hence you need to run the client software on the remote machine from the one you are running scp on.

If copying on the command line, use:

```bash
# copy from local machine to remote machine
scp localfile user@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

or

```bash
# copy from remote machine to local machine
scp user@host:/path/to/remotefile localfile
```

Comment: You are the man. I deployed a blog in less than 10 seconds without any additional installation on server side!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used msysgit in cmd since it has both scp and ssh.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used scp * user@host:/path/to/where

Comment: That should be the top answer.

Comment: If I have a file on my laptop (mac using terminal) surely I run the command to copy from that to the server I want the file on. How could a remote server access my laptop that isn't set up as some kind of server? When trying this I get - Permission denied (publickey) I think I need to get my login somehow automated as I pass the path every time to my key when logging in.

Comment: Thanks for the WinSCP suggestion. Way easier than trying to write all those commands manually...

Comment: Good mention of Nautilus having SCP integrated. Way easier for adhoc transfers than messing around with terminal. Basically your server connection is mounted like a volume.

Comment: Is there a linux alternative to WinSCP?

Comment: If you have to pass a key just `scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME`

Answer (score 23):

You need to specify both source and destination, and if you want to copy directories you should look at the -r option.

So to recursively copy /home/user/whatever from remote server to your current directory:

```
scp -pr user@remoteserver:whatever .
```

Answer (score 20):

No, you still need to `scp [from] [to]` whichever way you're copying

The difference is, you need to `scp -p server:serverpath localpath`

Comment: what is the purpose of -p?

Comment: From `man scp`: Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.

Comment: To be clear `-p` is only included here because the OP included the flag in their original question. It's not in any way relevant to the answer