# Transfer file over ssh

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

In ssh protocol, is there a mechanism for file transfer?
Im working on a existing code base which already has ssh facilities code. Now i need to transfer files over ssh connection. If ssh protocol already support it, i don't have to integrate scp stuff into it.

Thanks.

Edit:
Im using C, ssh code based on openssh.
I have to transfer the file programmingly, not using a external program/command because of some constraints. The program supposed to transfer any size file on remote host chunk-by-chunk, and process the chunk on-the-fly. Then the chunk data is discarded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transferring files over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh)

Answer (score 22):

```
echo "hello" | ssh user@SSHHost "cat - > /tmp/file"
```

I juste read the file, pipe it in SSH, and write on the SSHHost server in the /tmp/file.

Comment: I have to programmingly transfer the file, because there are some memory/hard-disk restraints.

Comment: +1 for the good 'ol days :-) I realize this post is old, but you can do this in a scriptable fashion using ssh keys: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 5):

sftp and scp are both existing "secure" file transfer methods, but your answers are going to depend on what technology stack you are using for your application.  You don't mention whether you're using C#, PHP or another language, or what kind of machine your app runs on.  These things will have a big bearing on the answers you will get.

Answer (score 4):

The old-school way is "tar-to-tar" which does a good job of copying and preserving permissions.  This has largely be superseded by use of rsync when both sides have rsync.

```
ssh test@example.org "cd mydir && tar cfp - mysubdir" | tar xvfp -
```

Be careful about sparse files, etc, when you do this.  Most tars have an option to preserve file holes during this sort of process.

Comment: Keep in mind BOTH sides have to be able to use rsync

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol).

**Edit:** You might also find [this article](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) useful regarding running rsunc over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync can be of help:

```
rsync usernamea@server.com:filename remotefilename
```

Comment: it seems unfortunately rsync has to be available on both machines

Answer (score 0):

```
To download: remote -> local
scp user@remote_host:remote_file local_file 

To upload: local -> remote
scp local_file user@remote_host:remote_file
```

For multiple files,  include `-r` after scp.