# How to download folder from putty using ssh client

Tags: ssh, putty

how to download folder(contains folder inside folder and files) from putty using  ssh client
i want download entire Dump to local Drive...
can any one guide me ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transferring files over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh)

Answer (score 38):

You need to use some kind of file-transfer protocol (ftp, scp, etc), putty can't send remote files back to your computer.  I use Win-SCP, which has a straightforward gui.  Select SCP and you should be able to log in with the same ssh credentials and on the same port (probably 22) that you use with putty.

Comment: Thanks, it is easy to use. The UI similar as FileZilla. Just input the IP, Host + Pwd, then can copy and paste from/to server/local pc.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to download the files, but you can use [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) from the PuTTY developers to get the files or dump any directory that you want.

Please see the following link on how to download a file/folder:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

Answer (score 12):

If you need to download a folder via a Linux command try this out:

`$ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt -r /some/local/directory`

Sources:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/useing-scp-to-copy-entire-directories-with-sub-folders-362842/
- http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Related Post:
[How to download a file from server using SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh?answertab=votes#tab-top)

8)

Comment: What is `-r` and why are you downloading a `.txt` doc and not a folder?

Comment: The question is clearly about doing this with putty.

Answer (score 1):

I use both PuTTY and Bitvise SSH Client.  PuTTY handles screen sessions better, but Bitvise automatically opens up a SFTP window so you can transfer files just like you would with an FTP client.