# How to download a file from server using SSH?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I need to download a file from server to my desktop. (UBUNTU 10.04) I don't have a web access to the server, just ssh.

If it helps, my OS is Mac OS X and iTerm 2 as a terminal.

Comment: Try out this sftp :  http://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: why is this off topic?

Comment: because it is not a programming question

Comment: @EdwardBlack could have been migrated to unix.stackexchange instead

Comment: This worked for me
`sudo scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@remotehost.io:Downloads/filename.sql  ~/Desktop`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1165, accepted):

In your terminal, type:

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /local/dir
```

replacing the username, host, remote filename, and local directory as appropriate.

If you want to access EC2 (or other service that requires authenticating with a private key), use the `-i` option:

```
scp -i key_file.pem your_username@remotehost.edu:/remote/dir/foobar.txt /local/dir
```

From: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: Is it possible to use with Amazon EC2?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon EC2, but if you have SSH access to your server, it should work.

Comment: I think that there is a missing `/` between `your_username@remotehost.edu:` and `foobar.txt` in the above example.

Comment: @NiLL scp -i xxx.pem your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory

Comment: If you need to copy file from server that is available through proxy, first use this recipe http://superuser.com/a/320438/219739

Comment: how do I copy not only a file from a remote machine, but a directory?

Comment: @Alex add the -r option.

Comment: Silly question but how do I get the username? Can that just be root?

Comment: @Horak: Yeah, root should work.

Comment: Thanks josh, ok another silly question, how should I format my path? 

"~/Users/horak/"

I'm in a sensitive place, just don't want to much anything up :)

Comment: Useful info - I didn't realize you run this from your local machine, and not from the place you want to download from. so as Horak was asking, ~/ will dump it in your user directory like /Users/admin/ - I was logged in ssh remotely and wondered why it wasnt working.

Comment: Does not work, i tried ´scp your_username@remotehost:foobar.txt C:\´ to save it on my C drive, but it did not worked.

Comment: Add `-P port` option to connect to a specific port (half an hour to realize that it wasn't `-p`

Comment: what I am using windows?

Comment: @FernandoZ the easiest solution would be to download WinSCP and use that, but if you want to do it from the command-line in Windows, I recommend downloading Cmder.  That should have scp (and several other Linux tools) built into it.  Another alternative would be to download GnuWin32, which is another set of Linux tools for Windows.

Comment: how to download folder using scp command in ubuntu?

Answer (score 322):

You can do this with the `scp` command. `scp` uses the SSH protocol to copy files across system by extending the syntax of `cp`.

Copy something from another system to this system:

```
scp username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
```

Copy something from this system to some other system:

```
scp /path/to/local/file username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file
```

Copy something from some system to some other system:

```
scp username1@hostname1:/path/to/file username2@hostname2:/path/to/other/file
```

Comment: I like how if one wanted to achieve OPs question and didnt fully read your answer they might accidently and without thinking simply run your first command and possibly overwrite the remote file they are trying to download with the local file they may have touched earlier. oops.

Comment: Why there are accesses for? Someone can do "rm -rf /" without thinking but that does not reduce the utility of rm command ?

Comment: Do you think that starting an answer to "how should I upgrade linux?" with the "rm -rf /" command would also be a good idea?

Comment: @MrPurple - Thanks for the warning, I almost did exactly that. I have edited the question to show the most relevant command first

Answer (score 96):

scp is certainly the way to go, but for completeness you can also do:

```
$ ssh host 'cat /path/on/remote' > /path/on/local
```

or

```
$ cat /path/on/local | ssh host 'cat > /path/on/remote'
```

Note, this is UUOC, but `< /path/on/local ssh host 'cat > /path'` could cause unnecessary confusion.

And to proxy between two hosts:

```
$ ssh host1 'cat /path/on/host1' | ssh host2 'cat > /path/on/host2'
```

Comment: http://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: Has anyone done a speed test on the different methods? I'd be curious to know which one's fastest. Use case: I have a huge file to download.

Comment: This actually works with .ssh/config, whereas scp doesn't seem to follow the ssh configuration

Answer (score 13):

If the SSH server support SFTP subsystem (this is part of SSH, and *unrelated* to FTP), use sftp. If it don't, try scp.

[CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) support all of them.

Comment: Download from their web site, http://cyberduck.ch/Cyberduck-4.2.1.zip

Comment: It looks like they have since changed the software to be free, but you can optionally donate any amount and that will get rid of a "donation prompt" from within the program.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It does, it's easy enough to download using Cyberduck's SFTP

Comment: FileZilla works great for me, and is free and open source (and made by the same guys that makes Firefox). as does Cygwin.

Comment: Not exactly sure how one would consider the SSH File Transfer Protocol  an invalid answer for a question about SSH file transfers. Perfectly adequate solution