# Copy files from Linux server using ssh client with different user name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have this linux machine with ssh server installed, I can access the server using username="**ubuntu**". ssh server blocks clients that try to connect using "`root`" username.

So connection can be made by:

```
ssh -i mykey ubuntu@myserver
```

I can get files that belong to "ubuntu" using :

```
scp -i mykey ubuntu@myserver:<file location> ./
```

However, what I really want is to get files that belong to "root" username, (Note: I can't access the server with username "root" for obvious security reasons).

so is there a way to do download files that are under "root" username?

I was thinking to do some magic in the server side that enables me to do that.(I don't know how :) )

if this help: I have root access and also I can create files on my server side. but I'm not allowed to change the file permission under the root(if someone get hold of these files I'll be fired)

Answer (score 1):

You can try monster like this

```
ssh ubuntu@myhost 'sudo cat /path/to/file | uuencode' | uudecode > path/to/local
```

You should have `uuencode` and `uudecode` on coresponding hosts.

Or if file is text you can skip uuencode part

ps: see related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this code, it gets stuck for some reason. instead of using "su" I use "sudo su". could that be a problem?

Comment: It probably wait for password. Try to find options to pass password as parameter to `su`

Comment: I just changed the code to 'sudo cat /path/to/file' and it worked. (since only text files are copied I didn't used uuencode). thx mate, it helped alot. could you just change the code so I can tick it as answered

Comment: I changed my sampe. But for other people it may need another way to get required permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the other way around.

Log into the the pc with the file you want with

```
ssh ubuntu@myserver
```

Then gain superuser privileges

```
sudu su
```

and then copy the files you want

```
scp /the_file_you_want ubuntu@myhost:/the_location_and_filename_you_want
```

Some other ways you can find here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

Comment: The problem is my local machine is not accessible via ssh. (its not a server)

Comment: Ah, ok. So thats what I put the link in for. There you find some interesting ways to use tar for doing this without scp but only ssh

Answer (score 0):

enable ssh on your machine
(if fedora) (for ubuntu you can find command on google easily)

```
 service sshd on
```

From your local machine

```
 ssh -i ubuntu@myserver
```

change to root

```
su
```

enter password

and copy files using scp

```
scp somefile.extension randomuser@localmachine:/some/path/
```

I hope it helps

Comment: that's the problem, I'm not able to enable ssh server on my local machine. its a windows machine under company's router. so there absolutely no way)