# How to write on XML file in Windows Server from FreeBSD?

Tags: xml, sh, windows-server-2008-r2, freebsd

Hello guys today I fell on a very difficult task and I need some help. I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 and a FreeBSD 9.3 server. In FreeBSD there are some `sh` files that open and close the server's ports. When a port opens/closes I want the `sh` file to edit an XML located in Windows Server and I have no idea how to do that. I appreciate any tips.

Comment: I don't exactly understand but if you could mount the windows server on the freebsd you could then edit the files every time the scripts are run.

Comment: The 2 servers are not in the same machine so I don't think I can do that.

Comment: you will need to find a way to expose the XML, maybe an FTP server so that when the ``sh`` scripts are run they could fetch the files, edit and later upload back again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use SSH for that purpose. You can [config key authorization](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) and use `scp` to store file to freeBSD edit it and load back XML files. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh) on using `scp`.