# How to revert my codebase back to my most recent deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I have the following scenario.

On December 6th my team and I deployed our codebase into production. Since that date, we have made several changes that have broken the codebase in ways that we have not foreseen. The codebase is an old legacy codebase with hardly any tests, coverage, lots of code smells, and very tightly coupled models. Despite our best efforts in piecemeal refactoring and testing what we could, the app broke and now its hard for us to determine how to fix the app. Our development practice does not advocate continuous deployment and huge chunks of code get deployed monthly (We are working on that). We are not under pressure but we are having a very hard time trying to find a commit that works the way it did before.

My question is if whether there is a way to get the codebase that is currently on production as is and get that back as our starting point. For example, we use capistrano to deploy the codebase onto EC2 with git. Can either git, AWS EC2, or Capistrano allow us to simply grab the code from there and simply use that to reset our git code?

It doesn't sound easy but I think that maybe someone out there knows of a way to do it. Does anyone out there know of a way to a). Grab the code on production b). Use that copy of the code to act as a reference to return our development code to that point.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can't you see on which commit HEAD is pointing on production and go back to that commit ?

Comment: Yes, like Corentin hinted at, something along the lines of `git branch recovery origin/HEAD` would recreate a branch from this point.

Comment: This is why you should create a separate branch when you actually release (and call it Release with the version number in the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options. The first is using capistrano. Following the steps [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/10105-capistrano-how-to-find-out-which-version-of-your-application-is-currently-live), you can setup the following capistrano script:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Show deployed revision'
  task :revision do
    on roles :app do |host|
      within current_path do
        info "#{host}: #{capture :cat, 'REVISION'}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `capistrano production deploy:revision`. which will output something like this:

```
$ cap production deploy:revision
00:00 deploy:revision
      app01.example.com: cf8734ece3938fc67262ad5e0d4336f820689307
      app02.example.com: cf8734ece3938fc67262ad5e0d4336f820689307
      app03.example.com: cf8734ece3938fc67262ad5e0d4336f820689307
```

There's your commit hash, `cf8734ece3938fc67262ad5e0d4336f820689307`. You can then just `git checkout d231b7abd6e4183e037817780738c54f1fbaf1fa` which will bring you to the exact commit you want. Now make a new branch with

```
git checkout -b 'last_deployed_code'
git push origin last_deployed_code`
```

or as @RomainValeri commented:

```
git branch recovery origin/cf8734ece3938fc67262ad5e0d4336f820689307
```

You've now got a new branch on github with the exact code you want.

Your second option is a bit uglier but no less effective. Assuming you're happy with scp (more reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh) if you're not - it's really simple), SSH into your server, navigate to your 'app' directory, and then copy that whole directory to your local machine.

You can then create a new branch or simply force push to master and hey presto, you've got a branch on github that exactly mirrors your deployed code. The first option is definitely preferred as there maybe some config files that you don't actually want to copy over from your prod app directory