# How to copy a directory from linux(remote system) to windows(local system)

Tags: unix

I am trying to copy a directory from linux (remote machine) to windows (local machine). Can you guys please tell me the command to do that.

Example: from "/home/tmp" to "C:\TEMP"

Comment: you can use ssh server

Comment: Yuu should indicate where are you stuck. Have you accessed to the linux machine? If so, how? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a utility to zip the folder into a zip file (on your linux node) using:

```
zip -r temp.zip /home/tmp
```

After that transfer it to your local as a simple single file using sftp. 
And at last unzip it on windows machine (using java.util.zip).

```
 /**
 * Unzip it
 * @param zipFile input zip file
 * @param output zip file output folder
 */
public void unZipFolder(String zipFile, String outputFolder){

 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

 try{

    //create output directory is not exists
    File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    //get the zip file content
    ZipInputStream zis = 
        new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    //get the zipped file list entry
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

    while(ze!=null){

       String fileName = ze.getName();
       File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

       System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        //create all non exists folders
        //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
        new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        fos.close();   
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }

    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is through ssh server. For that you have to install ssh server in linux system ([openssh](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3606) for ubuntu) and on window (for eg: [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)) also. After that you can able to transfer file throught scp command. For detail [Transferring files over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh)

Comment: I am using scp cmd only but i dont know how to give the destination

Answer (score 0):

use sftp client like http://openssh.en.softonic.com/. Still  a very basic question. Should have done some search before asking