# Import a database with ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have two server for my website. The first is production and the second is development.

With Amazon, I save my production database every night. And for my tests, I download my production database in my computer from Amazon.

I access to my development server by ssh. My issue is that I want to import my database from Amazon on my development server but I have no idea of how I can import my database with ssh.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SCP or "Secure Copy" utility to transfer files over SSH.  This of course won't let you import your database with ssh, but it will allow you to copy your database backup to and from your local machine and import and export normally with whatever database you are using.

See this question for more details.

[Transferring files over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh)