# Apache won't set headers for PHP script

Tags: php, apache, mod-expires, mod-fcgid, mod-headers

This `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 month"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header merge X-ModHeaders "Yes, it is installed"
</IfModule>
```

... works as expected in my development box (Windows box, Apache/2.4.10, PHP running as Apache module), where "works" means that it generates the appropriates headers for all resources (static or dynamic).

However, in my production server (Linux box, Apache/2.2.31, PHP running as FastCGI with mod_fcgid/2.3.9) it only works for static assets, not for PHP scripts.

Am I right suspecting that difference comes from the PHP SAPI? Is there a way to fix it so I don't need to duplicate the code that generates HTTP headers?

Comment: PHP can edit headers but that doesn't mean it will by default. You should still get these at any rate

Comment: Think the answer here applies: http://serverfault.com/questions/383011/mod-headers-not-sending-headers-when-file-is-php ... didn't dig in too deep but read those bug reports it references.

Comment: Is your production box on shared hosting? This might prevent you from changing certain apache modules...

Comment: @ficuscr That's certainly my problem but the only answer so far claims it isn't a bug and links a ticket that talks about something else. Yuk..

Comment: @LucLaverdure - Yes, it's shared hosting. What exactly would I be able to change if it was a dedicated server?

Comment: You'd be able to change everything on dedicated, what shared hosting do you have? There might be solutions looking for something specific to this hosting provider

Comment: Maybe [`Header always merge X-ModHeaders "Yes, it is installed"`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header)?

Comment: @bishop Sorry, I've tried all variations and it doesn't seem to be that. If the module generates any output, it's just wiped out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If PHP is running via mod_proxy_fcgi there might be no filesystem directory involved, hence no htaccess lookup can occur.

There is a more recent flavor of php+mod_proxy_fcgi now documented in the manual that uses SetHandler instead of ProxyPass -- that allows things like htaccess to be processed because the core actually looks up the URL in the filesystem as a first step.

Comment: Server is using "mod_fcgid/2.3.9" and `.htaccess` is certainly executed since other modules work as expected (e.g. `mod_rewrite` or the `AddHandler` directive to select the PHP version) and invalid directives cause a Status 500 response.

Comment: BTW, I've updated the question with the actual CGI handler I'm using (it wasn't mod_fastcgi but mod_fcgid, my bad)

Comment: For me this was the reason: I switched to the PHP Module on my shared hoster, and then `Header set` worked.

Comment: I eventually got confirmation from HSP support than their mod_fcgid setup prevented custom headers set in .htaccess from working. (I'm terribly sorry for not reporting back at the time!)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález do you have more information on this please? You know what exactly they've fixed? I am having the exact same problem...

Comment: @AdrianFöder They haven't fixed anything as far as I know. My hosting provider's specific set up does not allow those directives to have effect on the files they process. But since the problem only affects PHP files it's trivial to write a PHP workaround using `header()`.