# Setting headers in httpd.conf not setting headers in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I have a curious issue:

I have a bunch of headers that are the same for every website on a server. I think " *this can be set just once in `httpd.conf` so as to save writing out into a pile of .htaccess every time there's a new one to add / change.* "

So this is what I do;

In the `httpd.conf` file **before the virtual hosts** I set:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <Directory '/'>
Header always set Feature-Policy "accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'"
Header always set Cache-Control no-cache,must-revalidate
Header always set X-Clacks-Overhead "GNU Terry Pratchett"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection 1;mode=block
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header always set Content-Language en
Header always set Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset X-Powered-By
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"
Header always set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

However, after doing this and hard restarting the Apache (version 2.4.37), I find that additional or edited `Header` instructions in the `.htaccess` are not being sent.

For example; each account has its own CSP policy and this is reflected in the account `public_html/.htaccess` file:

*example:*

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self' https:;"
```

But when the headers are read by any browser the headers recieved are only the ones from the httpd.conf and no addditional or changed headers are showing from the `.htaccess`.

I can't work out why this is?

## What have I tried

- I have wrapped the headers in the `.htaccess` in qualifier `<IfModule  ...>` statements.
- I have used different browsers to force apache to reread the
  .htaccess files.
- I have read google and can find no reference of httpd.conf messing with htaccess reading of headers.
- Other parts to the `.Htaccess` files are being read ok.

## Notes

- Apache version 2.4.37
- All of these headers work in the `.htaccess` prior to the above changes. It's *not* Header syntax as far as I can tell.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. For me headers from both places i,e. `vhost.conf` and `.htaccess` are seen be client.

Comment: Hi @anubhava -- whereabouts are you putting the headersin the vhost.conf file -- before or after the vhost definitions?

Comment: I am putting all of your first section before my vhost definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found after much exploring that the reason this occurred was due to PHP being run via a CGI handler. Changing to `suphp` handler immediately resolved this issue.

Please see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259981/htaccess-headers-being-ignored-by-apache/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147413/apache-wont-set-headers-for-php-script).