# Putting hsts headers in apache using htaccess or httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, hsts

I have purchased a ssl certificate recently and have redirected all my traffic on secured https way but i want to get included in hsts preload list. For that reason i want to include hsts header. Is there any way using .htaccess or httpd.conf or if there is another way then please tell me in detail

Answer (score 3):

you can set the hsts header in a .htaccess file:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

@see [How to set HSTS header from .htaccess only on HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144552/how-to-set-hsts-header-from-htaccess-only-on-https) for more information

or with php:

```php
header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can put HSTS header on application side, I mean PHP. Add following code top of your header.php or index.php

```
<?php header("strict-transport-security: max-age=600");
```

People who uses shared hosting does not have an access to apache.conf. So proper way to do this is putting it on apache.conf.