# How to disable HSTS header with HTTP?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, preload, hsts

I have inserted the following in the .htaccess of my site in order to be admitted to the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/):

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"   
</ifModule>
```

The problem is that when I submit my site, I obtain:

> Warning: Unnecessary HSTS header over HTTP.
>   The HTTP page at
>   http: //fabriziorocca.it sends an HSTS header. This has no effect over
>   HTTP, and should be removed.

At the moment I use the following in the .htaccess in order to switch from http to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HSTS header from .htaccess only on HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144552/how-to-set-hsts-header-from-htaccess-only-on-https)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"
</ifModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This line worked for me `Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"` it required the single quotes on the 'on'

note: do not remove the keyword `always`

Answer (score 1):

Below your redirect rules add the code:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; 
includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

Answer (score 1):

I added in htaccess works perfectly for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"
```

env=HTTPS not works now.

Answer (score 0):

No...
Error: HTTP redirects to www first
`http://domain.fr` (HTTP) should immediately redirect to `https://domain.fr` (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. Right now, the first redirect is to `https://www.domain.fr/`. The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.