# how do make a correct scp copy in bash

Tags: bash

my command is

```
scp .deploy/deploy.sh root@192.168.155.148
```

I double checked it with this forum
[Transferring files over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh)

however it doesn't give any error, neither it does the copy.
I also do lot of ssh at root@192.168.155.148, without problem

am I missing something? even if I change the address to have a bad address, it doesn't give me error... but since ssh connect with the same root@... I guess the address should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a colon at the end of the command,

```
scp .deploy/deploy.sh root@192.168.155.148:
```

Or, if you want to put it in another directory under `/root/temporary`, for example, try,

```
scp .deploy/deploy.sh root@192.168.155.148:./temporary
```

Comment: wow thanks... actually I don't get it because I gave it a try before... oh well now it works it's what matter!!