# Transfer data between two VM instance on google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to transfer big files (over 2 GB) between google cloud VM instances without downloading and then uploading?

Comment: You can use ```SCP``` command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343711/transferring-files-over-ssh

Comment: Agree, it's not a Google Cloud specific question, but a general Linux file transfer.

Comment: I understand I can use `SCP` to transfer files between two computers, but I am curious is there a better way to deal with this data collection.